# Is there a way to empty a row of images and populate that row again without removing click listeners from the images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I'm writing a simple memory game where the objective is to click on images.

Once one is clicked, the images will be displayed in a new order on the page. If you click on an image that you've already clicked on, you will lose and the game resets.

The problem I'm encountering is that upon rotating and displaying in a new order, the event listeners seem to have been wiped off of the images. No console logs show up after the new order is display, which should be happening.

The images are dynamically loaded from an array of images: None are static on the HTML page. Said images are appended to a `Bootstrap-4` row.

I have a button that resets the images and sorts them in a new order via a `sortArray()` function. Said function is called in the `imgRandom()` function. This function is called whenever a button with the id `#resetGame` is clicked. the goal is to also call `imgRandom()` whenever an image is clicked, as well.

I've tried using `$(row).empty` to remove the images, but when I started to think it was removing the eventListeners, I tried using `$(row).detach()`, to no avail.

```
var imgArr = new Array(
{image: "cowboy-bebop-0.jpg", wasClicked: false}, 
{image: "cowboy-bebop-1.jpg", wasClicked: false}, 
{image: "cowboy-bebop-2.jpg", wasClicked: false},
{image: "cowboy-bebop-3.jpg", wasClicked: false},
{image: "cowboy-bebop-4.jpg", wasClicked: false},
{image: "cowboy-bebop-5.jpg", wasClicked: false},
{image: "cowboy-bebop-6.jpg", wasClicked: false});

var basePath = "assets/imgs/";

var row = $("<div class='row'></div>");

imgRandom();

function imgRandom()
{
    sortArray();
    $("#images").append(row);
    for (var i = 0; i < imgArr.length; i++) 
    {
        var image = new Image(200, 200);
        image.src = basePath + imgArr[i].image;
        $(image).css({"margin": "10px 10px"});
        $(image).addClass("col-lg-3");
        $(row).append(image);
    }
}

function sortArray()
{
    imgArr.sort(function(a,b)
    {
        return 0.5 - Math.random();
    });
}

$("#resetGame").on("click", function()
{
    //$(row).empty(); Failed attempts
    //$(row).detach(); Failed Attempts
    $("img").detach();
    console.log("row emptied");
    imgArr.forEach(function(element)
    {
        wasClicked = false;
        console.log(element.wasClicked);
    });
    imgRandom();
});

$("img").on("click", function()
{
    this.wasClicked = true;
    console.log("this images wasClicked value is now " + this.wasClicked);
});
```

There are some console.log()'s in there to see if the `eventListener` is listening, but after the `resetGame` button is clicked, the console logs don't show up anymore. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies within your `imgRandom()` function. If you run your script for the first time, it will execute imgRandom and append 7 `<img>` elements to the DOM.

```
var image = new Image(200, 200);
```

That means as soon as the script reaches `$("img").on("click", function(){});` there will be the besaid 7 elements.

Now if you click on the 'reset' button it will call imgRandom() again which in turn will append 7 **new** image elements to the DOM. Unfortunately they didn't exist yet as the click event listener was added so there is no click event for them.

What you can do - though not elegant - is wrapping `$("img").on` inside a function and call that again within imgRandom().

Here's an example:

```js
var imgArr = new Array({
  image: "https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/200",
  wasClicked: false
}, {
  image: "https://picsum.photos/id/2/200/200",
  wasClicked: false
});
var row = $("<div class='row'></div>");
var basePath = "";
imgRandom();

function imgRandom() {
  sortArray();
  $("#images").append(row);
  for (var i = 0; i < imgArr.length; i++) {
    var image = new Image(200, 200);
    image.src = basePath + imgArr[i].image;
    $(image).css({
      "margin": "10px 10px"
    });
    $(image).addClass("col-lg-3");
    $(row).append(image);
  }
  attachListeners();
}

function sortArray() {
  imgArr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
  });
}

$("#resetGame").on("click", function() {
  //$(row).empty(); Failed attempts
  //$(row).detach(); Failed Attempts
  $("img").detach();
  console.log("row emptied");
  imgArr.forEach(function(element) {
    wasClicked = false;
    console.log(element.wasClicked);
  });
  imgRandom();
});

function attachListeners() {
  $("img").on("click", function() {
    this.wasClicked = true;
    console.log("this images wasClicked value is now " + this.wasClicked);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="images">

</div>
<button id="resetGame">
reset
</button>
```

#### Addition

A more elegant way is to only instantiate, attach the click event listeners and add the 7 image elements to the DOM once. There's no need to do this over and over again. If you want to change the image - e.g. because you resorted the array - you can do this by using it's **.src** property.

In my example above and in the following I appended the images to a div called images. To get it's children - thus the images - you can use

```
$("#images img")
```

and to change the src properties of those to the urls inside the array:

```
  $("#images img").each(function(index) {
    $(this)[0].src = imgArr[index].image;
  });
```

Here's the more advanced example:

```js
var imgArr = new Array({
  image: "https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/200",
  wasClicked: false
}, {
  image: "https://picsum.photos/id/2/200/200",
  wasClicked: false
}, {
  image: "https://picsum.photos/id/3/200/200",
  wasClicked: false
}, {
  image: "https://picsum.photos/id/4/200/200",
  wasClicked: false
});
var row = $("<div class='row'></div>");
var basePath = "";
initializeImages();
imgRandom();

function initializeImages() {
  $("#images").append(row);
  for (var i = 0; i < imgArr.length; i++) {
    var image = new Image(200, 200);
    image.src = basePath + imgArr[i].image;
    $(image).css({
      "margin": "10px 10px"
    });
    $(image).addClass("col-lg-3");
    $(row).append(image);
  }
  $("img").on("click", function() {
    this.wasClicked = true;
    imgRandom();
    console.log("this images wasClicked value is now " + this.wasClicked);
  });
}

function imgRandom() {
  sortArray();
  $("#images img").each(function(index) {
    $(this)[0].src = imgArr[index].image;
  });
}

function sortArray() {
  imgArr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
  });
}

$("#resetGame").on("click", function() {
  imgArr.forEach(function(element) {
    wasClicked = false;
    console.log(element.wasClicked);
  });
  imgRandom();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="images">

</div>
<button id="resetGame">
  reset
</button>
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you! But I do have a follow up question: Without getting too in-depth in a comment, would the best option be to remove the objects completely from the dom then reattach listeners or is there a better work around for this?

Comment: No problem OppulentHippo! I refined my answer above. =)

Comment: Definitely is more refined, but I'm getting broken images with the new method lol, even when straight copy/pasting in (I left my basePath variable untouched, I only copied the functions and function calls). the console shows that they are getting arranged randomly though lol. I wonder what I'm missing

Comment: I figured it out, I just need to add my basePath to the src, so it looks like:
$(this)[0].src = basePath + imgArr[index].image; You've been a tremendous help, obscure. thank you!

Comment: Glad you could figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moving the images, you could store the positions of each image source, then rotate the sources instead of the images themselves? Here is what I mean:

//An array to store the image sources

```
var sources = new Array(
    "cowboy-bebop-0.jpg"
    "cowboy-bebop-1.jpg"
    "cowboy-bebop-2.jpg"
    "cowboy-bebop-3.jpg"
    "cowboy-bebop-4.jpg"
    "cowboy-bebop-5.jpg"
);
```

//This array would store the position of each source (IE: The Image object uses it)

```
var positions = new Array(
    0,
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
);
```

//This array would store your Image objects

```
var images = new Array(6);
```

Now instead of rotating the  images, all you would have to do is rotate the positions of the image sources and update the images with the new sources